# Loaders vs. Asyncctask vs. others

Tags: android

In my app, I need to update the database with some data from the server. The data need not be shown to the user immediately. It is also fine if the new data is shown to the user the next time he uses the app. There is no UI component that needs to be updated now because of this operation. So, I just need to fetch some data from the server in the background, when the app is running.

currently I am using an Asynctask in an activity. But it does not handle configuration changes well. So, I was reading up a bit and came across a few options:

1. Using Loaders
2. Using Fragments
3. Using Asynctask in a fragment
4. Using static Asynctask

I am a bit new to this and am quite confused what would be the best implementation method for my requirement. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it might help someone. What I have done to fix this is:

Use an alarmmanager to setrepeating alarm that would invoke a service at specific intervals to fetch the data. Something like the code below is called the first time the app runs.

```
Intent i = new Intent(WordListActivity.this, NewData.class);
            PendingIntent pint = PendingIntent.getService(
                    WordListActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
            alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 10000,
                    gap, pint);
```